# how to feel data into TableView in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

I'm  going to create `desktop application`. In my application the database on the server and client just request to server to fetch data and return the object of the appropriate class.

```
public void serveStudentList() {
    BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
    ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
    Session sess = null;
    Transaction tx = null;
    try {
        bos = new BufferedOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);

        sess = HUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        tx = sess.beginTransaction();
        sess = HUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Student> students = sess.createQuery("FROM Student").list();

        tx.commit();

        System.out.println("DATABASE query complete.\nWriting Object of List type to the Sream.");

        oos.writeObject(students);
        oos.flush();
        System.out.println("Object Wrote...\n Closing this stream now.");
        oos.close();
        bos.close();
        con.close();


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (HibernateException he) {
        if (tx != null) {
            tx.rollback();
        }
        he.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        sess.close();
    }
```

Now I want to use this students object to fill the `TableView`.

I want fill data into TableView using simple String object, cant I do this ?

I don't want to use `SimpleStringPropery`, I want to use `String` object.
I'm using hibernate so I mapping my all classes

Comment: List<Student> students = sess.createQuery("FROM Student").list(); now i want to use this object to feel TableView. So How can i do this.

Comment: Create an `ObservalbleList<Student>` instead of `List<Student>`. Updating my answer !

Comment: You can certainly use Strings in the table columns instead of StringProperties. Assuming your Student class has getXXX() methods for its properties, just use a PropertyValueFactory as the CellValueFactory on the TableColumns. However, if you want the table to be editable, you will have some extra work to do.

Answer (score 1):

Just create an `ObservableList<Student>` and bind it with your table ! Simple !

You can make an `ObservableList<Student>` from your `List<Student>`

```
List<Student> students = sess.createQuery("FROM Student").list();
ObservableList<Student> listStudents = FXCollections.observableList(students);
TableView table = new TableView();
table.setItems(listStudents);
```

You will have to add `TableColumn` to the `TableView`, for a complete example, you can go through

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm#CJABHGAJ